# FIFO Queue connected to FIFO Topic won't receive message subsequent messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, localstack

I am using AWS SQS and SNS fifo variants to create a simple way of managing  events throughout my system. To preface this, my system is really tiny and not that complicated, but I decided that it would be a lot easier to manage the code itself if its split up into independent parts that are deployed as single binary. Not the topic of this question.

I am using Localstack here, to locally test and develop, not sure if their SQS/ SNS interaction is different which is causing this issue, if so, I'll move my question to their github repo.

So I have a FIFO topic per entity in my system, I'll  be taking project as an example, project is deployable website. So I have a FIFO Topic called project and in the message attributes I set the event type `ProjectCreated`, `ProjectRequested`... Based on the type, it gets routed to the appropriate SQS FIFO queue, like analytics, provisioning and so on.

The way I model the message is the following,

- the `body` contents are json
- message group id is the entity id, so all of the messages that are about a single entity are properly ordered
- message dedup id is the entity id + the operation, eg. `created-123`, `provisioned-123`, `deleted-123`. This ensures that there should be no duplicates at any given time for a single entity/ operation combination

This is the way I understood this would work, basically, the entities messages would be grouped and ordered by the entity itself (since we're using the id), and we couldn't have duplicate messages for a given operation until the previous one is deleted. But this is not the case.

To showcase this I created 2 new queues that subscribe to the FIFO `Project` topic, one is a FIFO queue, the other is standard queue, I also created a helper bash script to receive the messages

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# ./receive_sqs_messages.sh [--fifo]
#
# This script connects to a LocalStack instance and continuously receives messages from an SQS queue.
# Accepts --fifo flag to determine whether to use standard queue or fifo queue
# It echoes each message's metadata and content along with a timestamp, and then deletes the message.

# Set default queue name
QUEUE_NAME="test-queue"

# Check for --fifo flag
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ "$arg" == "--fifo" ]; then
        QUEUE_NAME="test-queue.fifo"
        break
    fi
done

# Get the Queue URL
QUEUE_URL=$(awslocal sqs get-queue-url --queue-name $QUEUE_NAME --output text)

echo "$(date): Listening for messages on $QUEUE_URL"

while true; do
    # Receive a message from the SQS queue
    RESPONSE=$(awslocal sqs receive-message --queue-url $QUEUE_URL --attribute-names All)

    # Check if the message is not empty
    if [ ! -z "$RESPONSE" ]; then
        # Extract message details
        MESSAGE_BODY=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.Messages[0].Body')
        RECEIPT_HANDLE=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle')

        # Echo the message and its metadata
        echo "$(date): Received a message - $MESSAGE_BODY"
        echo "Metadata: $RESPONSE"

        # Delete the message from the queue
        awslocal sqs delete-message --queue-url $QUEUE_URL --receipt-handle $RECEIPT_HANDLE
        echo "$(date): Deleted message with ReceiptHandle $RECEIPT_HANDLE"
    fi

    # Wait for a short period before the next loop iteration
    sleep 5
done
```

Lets take a look at the logs(excuse the cyrilic timestamps for the date)

First up the FIFO queue, it only receives the single event

```
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:04:47 CET: Listening for messages on http://sqs.eu-central-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000
000/test-queue.fifo
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:05:53 CET: Received a message - {"entityId":"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c","eventType":"Projec
tRequested"}
Metadata: {
    "Messages": [
        {
            "MessageId": "e5046b81-a8a1-46d1-990d-59b72c79938b",
            "ReceiptHandle": "MThkYjBlYTctMzFjZS00NTk3LThmNTQtMjA4NzdiNzBiMDI2IGFybjphd3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDA
wMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZS5maWZvIGU1MDQ2YjgxLWE4YTEtNDZkMS05OTBkLTU5YjcyYzc5OTM4YiAxNzA3MTIwMzUzLjcxMzM2ODI=",
            "MD5OfBody": "798357615efbbc6fe3a24ac5a8d0c107",
            "Body": "{\"entityId\":\"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c\",\"eventType\":\"ProjectRequested\"}",
            "Attributes": {
                "SenderId": "000000000000",
                "SentTimestamp": "1707120351448",
                "MessageGroupId": "65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c",
                "MessageDeduplicationId": "ProjectRequested-65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c",
                "SequenceNumber": "14664029547054235655",
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1707120353713"
            }
        }
    ]
}
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:05:54 CET: Deleted message with ReceiptHandle MThkYjBlYTctMzFjZS00NTk3LThmNTQtMjA4NzdiNzBiMDI2IGFybjph
d3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZS5maWZvIGU1MDQ2YjgxLWE4YTEtNDZkMS05OTBkLTU5YjcyYzc5OTM4YiAxNzA3MTIwM
zUzLjcxMzM2ODI=
```

But the standard queue receives all of them

```
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:04:49 CET: Listening for messages on http://sqs.eu-central-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000
000/test-queue
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:05:55 CET: Received a message - {"entityId":"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c","eventType":"Projec
tRequested"}
Metadata: {
    "Messages": [
        {
            "MessageId": "0cfc249e-dde4-4057-b6c7-a57e168cc7af",
            "ReceiptHandle": "NGRkZGY5OTUtODQxMC00NWY4LThhM2ItMjlmZjZjNDEzYmY0IGFybjphd3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDA
wMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZSAwY2ZjMjQ5ZS1kZGU0LTQwNTctYjZjNy1hNTdlMTY4Y2M3YWYgMTcwNzEyMDM1NS44MDUyMjM3",
            "MD5OfBody": "798357615efbbc6fe3a24ac5a8d0c107",
            "Body": "{\"entityId\":\"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c\",\"eventType\":\"ProjectRequested\"}",
            "Attributes": {
                "SenderId": "000000000000",
                "SentTimestamp": "1707120351443",
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1707120355805"
            }
        }
    ]
}
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:05:56 CET: Deleted message with ReceiptHandle NGRkZGY5OTUtODQxMC00NWY4LThhM2ItMjlmZjZjNDEzYmY0IGFybjph
d3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZSAwY2ZjMjQ5ZS1kZGU0LTQwNTctYjZjNy1hNTdlMTY4Y2M3YWYgMTcwNzEyMDM1NS44M
DUyMjM3
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:06:08 CET: Received a message - {"entityId":"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c","eventType":"Projec
tGenerated"}
Metadata: {
    "Messages": [
        {
            "MessageId": "5f2ec5a6-909a-4307-9034-ef4176b33446",
            "ReceiptHandle": "YTRlNDA5ZTAtODYyOS00MmExLThmZmYtNjY2NWIwY2I1OGJjIGFybjphd3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDA
wMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZSA1ZjJlYzVhNi05MDlhLTQzMDctOTAzNC1lZjQxNzZiMzM0NDYgMTcwNzEyMDM2OC43OTA2MTc3",
            "MD5OfBody": "229ce98e015502d0fce2b320e9f330f4",
            "Body": "{\"entityId\":\"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c\",\"eventType\":\"ProjectGenerated\"}",
            "Attributes": {
                "SenderId": "000000000000",
                "SentTimestamp": "1707120366073",
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1707120368790"
            }
        }
    ]
}
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:06:09 CET: Deleted message with ReceiptHandle YTRlNDA5ZTAtODYyOS00MmExLThmZmYtNjY2NWIwY2I1OGJjIGFybjph
d3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZSA1ZjJlYzVhNi05MDlhLTQzMDctOTAzNC1lZjQxNzZiMzM0NDYgMTcwNzEyMDM2OC43O
TA2MTc3
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:06:15 CET: Received a message - {"entityId":"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c","eventType":"Projec
tProvisioned"}
Metadata: {
    "Messages": [
        {
            "MessageId": "4930bfb7-c33c-431e-9114-545549574d86",
            "ReceiptHandle": "NDM5MTVkNTgtNTAyYS00ODEzLTk0YTYtYTRlNTIxZjJmMjU3IGFybjphd3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDA
wMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZSA0OTMwYmZiNy1jMzNjLTQzMWUtOTExNC01NDU1NDk1NzRkODYgMTcwNzEyMDM3NS43NjI3NDM1",
            "MD5OfBody": "8d69872b3328e917d7b2a1b59d411ac7",
            "Body": "{\"entityId\":\"65b151b8-b515-4478-82da-b479f8b8c85c\",\"eventType\":\"ProjectProvisioned\"}",
            "Attributes": {
                "SenderId": "000000000000",
                "SentTimestamp": "1707120366483",
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1707120375762"
            }
        }
    ]
}
пон,  5. феб 2024.  09:06:16 CET: Deleted message with ReceiptHandle NDM5MTVkNTgtNTAyYS00ODEzLTk0YTYtYTRlNTIxZjJmMjU3IGFybjphd3M6c3FzOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTowMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA6dGVzdC1xdWV1ZSA0OTMwYmZiNy1jMzNjLTQzMWUtOTExNC01NDU1NDk1NzRkODYgMTcwNzEyMDM3NS43NjI3NDM1
```

This is causing issues in my logic since if the same project is requested twice (second time due to failure or any other reason), the message is not being processed by the queue.

The logic for group id and dedup id

```golang
type EntityMessagePayload struct {
    Data      map[string]interface{} `json:"data ,omitempty"`
    EntityID  string                 `json:"entityId"`
    EventType MessageEventType       `json:"eventType"`
}

func (p EntityMessagePayload) DefaultDedupID() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", p.EventType, p.EntityID)
}

func (p EntityMessagePayload) DefaultGroup() string {
    return p.EntityID
}
```

The CDK code that sets up the SQS/ SNS

```js
        this.projectTopic = new sns.Topic(this, "ProjectTopic", {
            fifo: true,
            displayName: "Project topic",
            topicName: "project.fifo",
        });

        const subOpts = { rawMessageDelivery: true };


        if (isLocal(props.deployEnv)) {
            const testQueue = new sqs.Queue(this, "TestQueue", {
                queueName: "test-queue",
                fifo: false,
            })

            const testFifoQueue = new sqs.Queue(this, "TestFifoQueue", {
                queueName: "test-queue.fifo",
                fifo: true,
            })

            this.projectTopic.addSubscription(new subscriptions.SqsSubscription(testQueue, subOpts));
            this.projectTopic.addSubscription(new subscriptions.SqsSubscription(testFifoQueue, subOpts));
        }
```

Comment: I wonder if the message is not being deleted correctly? That would cause subsequent messages with the same `MessageGroupId` to be blocked.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein other than that, what I have should work? If that's the case I can check the difference between `localstack` and live aws and see whether there is a difference in behavior

Comment: Also check whether more than one message was passed to your Receive request, or explicitly specify `--max-number-of-messages 1` -- if more than one is being provided and your code only deletes the first one (`Messages[0].ReceiptHandle`) then the others will sit there until they timeout again.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed in the latest version of LocalStack. There was a problem with the message group logic that was most commonly triggered in long-polling scenarios. A message group that had all its messages processed and was then targeted by another receive call would stop working.
For reference, here is the link to the PR that should solve this:
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/pull/10223

Disclaimer: I work for LocalStack